# Blazor consumes too much Memory

Tags: blazor, visual-studio-mac

I was testing Blazor and i found out something weird, probably something i did wrong, but the result is really weird. This is not a VM, is just my laptop (Macbook pro 16GB Ram) and 1 docker container with sql server linux.

I created a new component called Buildertest with an object as a parameter. if a run the project, dotnet comsumes at least 70 GB of Ram and a lot of CPU (thats the weird part). Normally visual studio takes me to the home page in chrome almost immediatley, but not this time. the code i think is very simple:

/index.razor:

```
@page "/"
@using Loginnmodels2.Data
@inject IModalService Modal

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.


<buildertest generic_object="a" />

@code
{
    private UserHasCases a = new UserHasCases();
}
```

Buildertest.cs:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Loginnmodels2.Pages
{
    public class buildertest : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter] public Loginnmodels2.Data.UserHasCases generic_object { get; set; }
        private PropertyInfo[] Propiedades;

        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
            GetListOfProperties();
            int counter = 0;

            builder.OpenElement(++counter, "table");
            builder.OpenElement(++counter, "tbody");
            foreach (var item in Propiedades)
            {
                builder.OpenElement(++counter, "tr");

                builder.OpenElement(++counter, "td");
                builder.AddContent(++counter, item.Name);
                builder.CloseElement();

                builder.OpenElement(++counter, "td");
                builder.OpenElement(++counter, "Input");
                builder.CloseElement();

                builder.CloseElement();

            }
            builder.CloseElement();
            builder.CloseElement();


        }   

        private void GetListOfProperties()
        {
            Propiedades = new PropertyInfo[5];
            Propiedades = generic_object.GetType().GetProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course im new into Blazor, but my guess is that somehow the parameter of the class buildertest brakes something.

any ideas? I'm using Visual Studio for Mac.

Activity Monitor screenshot

[image]

UserHasCases class:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Loginnmodels2.Data
{
    public class UserHasCases
    {
        public User usr {get; set;}
        public Case connected_case { get; set; }
        public int Sequence { get; set; }
        
        [Key] [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] public Int64 int_counter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this is the class i created as service

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using System.Data.Entity;
using Loginnmodels2.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Loginnmodels2.DataServices
{
    public interface IUserDataService
    {
        Task<List<Data.User>> Get();
        Task<Data.User> Get(string usr_name);
        Task<Data.User> Add(Data.User a);   
        Task<List<Data.UserHasCases>> GetCases(User param_usr);
        void Delete(Data.User a);
    }

    public class UserDataService : IUserDataService
    {
        dbcontext1 _context;

        public UserDataService(dbcontext1 ctx)
        {
            _context = ctx;
        }

        public async Task<List<Data.User>> Get()
        {
            return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<Data.User> Get(string usr_name)
        {
            return await GetAllUsers().Where(x => x.user_name == usr_name).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public async Task<Data.User> Add(Data.User a)
        {
            _context.Users.Add(a);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return a;
        }

        public async void Delete(Data.User a)
        {
            _context.Users.Remove(a);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();            
        }

        public IQueryable<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return _context.Users.AsQueryable();
        }

        private IQueryable<UserHasCases> GetAllCases()
        {
            return _context.UserCaseRelation.AsQueryable();
        }

        public async Task<List<Data.UserHasCases>> GetCases(User param_usr)
        {
            return await GetAllCases().Where(x => x.usr == param_usr).ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<List<Data.UserHasCases>> GetAllValidCases()
        {
            return await GetAllCases().Where(x => x.connected_case.is_valid == true).ToListAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

this is the setup in visual studio:
[Setup in vstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ1ZB.png)

Comment: Can you share your UserHasCases class so I can try to reproduce the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also, what version of .net core are  you running?

Comment: LOL, I first thought that GB was a typo. This must be some misconfigured VM or Docker container. Better add as many Apple related tags as you can find.

Comment: And list precisely your setup: tools, framework version etc.

Comment: the version of .net core is 3.1.0

Comment: found my problem..... in the file Buildertest.cs, line 34, im was missing a CloseElement();

quite hard to pinpoint....but still this is good stuff.

thanks guys for quick response :)

Comment: This makes it a relevant question, somebody might experience this again. You can post a self-answer to close the issue offically. Comments don't count here.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the builder.CloseElement(); was missing. This caused a weird behaviour in the Blazor Application.

Once the CloseElement was added, the whole app was working perfect.